# How do I integrate the answers from a file that I inputted with a file that I am reading from?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Kazarian_MadLibs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("Mad Libs 1.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println("Please provide a word for each of the following: ");
        PrintWriter answers = new PrintWriter("answers.txt");
        inputFile.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {

            System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
            String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            answers.println(answer);

        }
        answers.close();    
    }
}
```

I must put together a Mad Lib story with my answers on one text file and the story in another and link the two files together somehow. How can I approach this? Do I use another loop? The code above is what I have come up with so far. It essentially stores the answers in a separate text file

Comment: What does "Mad Libs 1.txt" look like?

Comment: 18
Name of person in room:
Same name of person in room:
Verb ending in "ing":
Verb:
Noun (plural):
Same name of person in room:
Adjective:
Adjective:
Noun (plural):
Place:
Same name of person in room:
Verb ending in "ed":
Emotion:
Adverb:
Adjective:
Noun (plural):
Same name of person in room:
Noun:

Comment: Batman is 
. Teenager 
 was traumatized by 
 his parent`s murder and vowed to 
 their deaths by bringing the 
 to justice. 
 used his 
 fortune to study criminology, to train his body to 
 perfection, and to acquire high tech vehicles and 
 to fight crime in his hometown of 
. One night 
 was 
 by a bat outside his window and decided to dress himself as a "bat man" to strike 
 in the "
 and 
" hearts of 
. From that moment forward, 
 became "Batman" in his altered 
.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? The first step in writing a working program is to clearly have in your head what it needs to do.

Comment: I need it to print that bat man story written in the "Mad Libs 1.txt" file and substitute my answers written in the "answers.txt" file.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to use String.format().  Change your Madlibs.txt to something like:

Batman is %1$c.  As a teenager, %1$c was traumatized by his parents murder and vowed to avenge their deaths by bringing the %2$c to justice.  %1$c used his fortune to study criminology...

The % sign means "this is something to format".  The 1$ means "use the first variable I give you".  "c" means "and treat it as a String".  (See java.util.Formatter for details.)

So, read in each of their inputs to a List.  Save those answers to a file.  Then do:

System.out.println(String.format(theStory, answers.toArray(new String[])));

This will take "theStory" and apply the answers to it.

Comment: I appreciate the response but this is far too advanced for me.

Comment: I was thinking more like a for loop that reads the story and somehow appends the answers from the other file to it

Comment: What part do you think is too advanced?  I can explain it in more detail.  How are you planning on inserting the answers into the story?